# SQL top 5 records algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

Let me be the first to admit that I am not the greatest with SQL and this issue has be slightly stumped.

I need to create an algorithm that will return the top 5 records from a table. The Top 5 records should be worked out by summing 3 columns together and the top 5 with the greatest score should be returned.

Can anyone give me some pointers in how I would do this kind of statement please.

I have been messing around with some code for a while and I am not getting anywhere fast.

Regards
Mark

Comment: Cheers for every ones help I forgot to mention the fact i was getting the values from 3 other tables but the information you all provided really helped me and it is all working as i need. Cheers again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried the following in SQL Server Management Studio and it seems to do what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM
(
     SELECT Value1, (Col1 + Col2 + Col3) AS Rank FROM MyTable
) tmp
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

---

**EDIT**
Just noticed that you actually don't need the outer select and can write:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Value1, (Col1 + Col2 + Col3) AS Rank FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

This was tested in SQL Server 2008.

---

It selects the value of a column and the sum of three other columns from a table called `MyTable` in the inner select. The outer select orders these by the selected sum and takes the top 5.

Example: The source table contains the following data

```
Value1    Col1    Col2    Col3
  V0        0       0       0
  V1        1       0       0
  V2        2       0       0
  V3        3       9       0
  V4        4       9       0
  V5        5       9       0
  V6        6       9       10
  V7        7       9       10
```

The inner select would create

```
Value1    Rank
  V0        0
  V1        1
  V2        2
  V3        12
  V4        13
  V5        14
  V6        25
  V7        26
```

And the outer select would return

```
Value1    Rank
  V7        26
  V6        25
  V5        14
  V4        13
  V3        12
```

Comment: You should have the Order By Rank inside the inner select. Currently that will give the top 5 results in whatever order the database returns and then order those 5 DESC.

Comment: Doesn't matter as the inner select returns all records anyway. The outer select then sorts these and selects the top 5.

Comment: ORDER BY column alias is fine in all versions of SQL Server.

Comment: cheers worked a treat with some minor tweaks to suit my needs (was getting column values from other tables but this helped me immensely)

Answer (score 4):

This might give you the desired effect:

`MySQL`

```
SELECT Value1, (Col1 + Col2 + Col3) AS Rank 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Rank DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

`SQL`

```
SELECT TOP 5 Value1, (Col1 + Col2 + Col3) AS Rank 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Rank DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses `TOP` to limit the number of records return on the `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Column1, (Column1 + Column2 + Column3) totalSum 
FROM   TableName
ORDER  BY totalSum  DESC
```

if you want to handle tie, add `WITH TIES` in the `TOP` clause,

```
SELECT TOP 5 WITH TIES Column1, 
       (Column1 + Column2 + Column3) totalSum 
FROM   TableName
ORDER  BY totalSum  DESC
```

- [TSQL TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try a combination of 'order by' and 'limit'.

```
select *, (col1 + col2 + col3) as total
  from MyTable
  order by total desc
  limit 5;
```

*Note, this is the syntax for mysql, not sql-server*

Comment: although the concept is correct but the syntax used is for `MySQL`.  -- not my downvote.